# Matching a string, but not when followed by numbers

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to get a match for a string, but only when that string isn't followed by a colon and some numbers.

I've gotten as far as: `(?<=REQUEST:V4:).*\:`

(BTW - I'd like to drop that colon from the result too)

This is some sample data to test against:

```
08:27:08,946 INFO  [com.cars.bdlx.manageinvoice.common.ManageInvoiceService-170] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-22) REQUEST:V4:dUowlr45NG88:GET_INVOICE_PDF InvoicePdfRequest[customerID=12345678,accountNumber=987654321,invoiceNumber=33333333,countryCode=UK,page=<null>,pageFrom=<null>,pageTo=<null>,copy=false,billingSystemID=MOB,date=<null>,brand=TIGER,callingSystem=Base,userId=777777777,additionalRights=<null>]

08:27:08,244 INFO [TIME-460] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-7) TIME:V4:YpXGo1j4dMcS:GET_INVOICE_PDF:0.048
```

Basically the first should be a hit while the second should not.

In the second sample, the result (a transaction ID and a method - GET.....) is followed by a time, and I don't want that to be a hit at all.

Comment: so, what's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this regex could be an option:

[`(?<=[A-Za-z]\d:)\w+(?=\D+ )`](https://regex101.com/r/OObMlU/1)

**Explanation**

- Assert with a positive lookbehind `(?<=`
- That what is before is a character, followed by a digit and a colon `[A-Z]\d+:`
- Match any word character `\w+` (or `[a-zA-Z\d]+`) one or more times
- Assert with a positive lookahead that what follows is not a digit one or more times followed by a white space `(?=\D+ )`

Or you could use [`(?<=REQUEST:V4:)\w+(?=\D+ )`](https://regex101.com/r/OObMlU/2)

Comment: Thanks for leading an old horse to water :)   Hadn't done this in a while and had forgotten but your tips led me to the following: REQUEST\:V.\:(?P<REQUEST_ID>.*?(?=(?::)|$))